# Ionic - disable hardware backbutton in Windows Phone 8.1 not working

Tags: android, visual-studio, windows-phone, ionic-framework

I'm developing using IONIC framework. I'm having trouble with the hardware back button.

In android the hardware back button works perfectly, but the windows phone did not work out.
When I use the back button on windows phone minimizes the application and returns the device's home.

This function only works on android:

```
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
            console.log("Not work in WP");
        }, 100);
```

help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found solution.

> In site
>   https://www.hoessl.eu/2014/12/on-using-the-ionic-framework-for-windows-phone-8-1-apps/
>   have a post calling -> Not fixed yet: Back Button
>
> Not fixed yet: Back Button
>
> With Windows Phone 8.0, listening on the “backbutton” event was pretty
>   simple, just as with android. On WP8.1, this event is not triggered
>   anymore. I haven’t figured out how to enable it yet. Any hint would be
>   appreciated.
>
> But a user commented the solution. follows the passage that worked in
>   my case

Back Button Fix :

Set your $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (evt) {
if (evt && evt.type == ‘backclick’) {
$ionicHistory.goBack();
return true;
}
}, 100);
```

Hookin WinJS and send it to Ionic :

```
if(ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone)
{
WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function (evt) {
$ionicPlatform.hardwareBackButtonClick(evt);
return true;
}
}
```

Easy Fix, long time figuring it out

Comment: hello , can you please tell me where can I put this codes ? do I need to put the code in every controller functions ? also hook in winjs only needs in one place right ?

Answer (score 1):

> Example for placing the code inside app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.menu', 'starter.services'])
  .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $state, ...) {

$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (evt) {
  if (evt && evt.type == 'backclick') {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
    return true;
  }
}, 100);

...
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  ...

  if (ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone()) {
    WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function (evt) {
      if ($state.current.name == 'app.home') {
        //function responsible for exiting the application in Windows phone 8.1
        cordova.exec(null, null, "ExitApp", "execute", []);
      } else {
        $ionicPlatform.hardwareBackButtonClick(evt);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});  ...

$stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    onEnter: function ($state, UserService) {
      console.log("##### - " + UserService.get().isLogged);
      if (UserService.get().isLogged) {
        $state.go("app.home");
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuCtrl'

  })
  .state('app.secretary', {
    url: '/secretary',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/secretary/menusecretary.html',
        controller: 'MenuSecretaryCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I figure it out and fixed, but now another problem is when this code `$ionicHistory.goBack(); ` is present  it will close the app by pressing hardware back button, when I comment above line it disabling the back button. What I'm planning is in the header I have an ionic back that works fine and exactly using default `$ionicHistory.goBack();` , When the user clicks on the device hardware I'm trying to trigger that header default button.